# pygame.draw.rect() function called in a class doesn't show the rectangle

Tags: python, pygame

The code down below doesn't show a rectangle called in a class that is stored in a list even if the order of the loop "draw-refresh" is right.

```py
while True:

     root.fill((0,200,255))

     for walls in range(len(WallList)):
          WallList[walls]
          print(walls, WallList[walls])

     for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

     pygame.display.update()
```

I expect the rectangles to be drawn before the root is filled, but the root is always blue (The color that I gave).

Edit: There's the class:

```py
class Wall():
     def __init__(self, x, y, thotType):
          global TypeList,camX,camY
          self.x=x
          self.y=y
          self.type=thotType
          if self.type== "Wall": pygame.draw.rect(root,(0,255,255),(x+camX,y+camY,mapmultiplier,mapmultiplier),1)
          if self.type== "Blank": pygame.draw.rect(root,(32,32,32),(x+camX,y+camY,mapmultiplier,mapmultiplier))
          TypeList.append(self.type)
```

Comment: Where exactly should  the rectangle be drawn in this code? What is `WallList[walls]` expected to do?

Comment: the rectangle position is ok, in fact that's not the problem. `WallList[walls]` calls the class that draws the rectangle at given position. I appent the classes to this list in the first piece of code.

Comment: I don't mean a position, I mean which line in the code. `WallList[walls]` doesn't call anything. Show the class, especially the method which is assumed to draw the rectangle.

Comment: In other words, you need code. probably a call to something, that _draws_ `WallList[walls]` because all what have does is access an element of the list, but doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: Don't put a that much code in a comment. Put it in your question.

Comment: I'm saying that with no "draw-refresh" code, it works. But with a simple `root.fill()` function, it doesn't work. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to add a method to the class, which draws the rectangle.

e.g.

```py
class Wall():
    def __init__(self, x, y, thotType):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.type=thotType
        TypeList.append(self.type)

    def draw(self):
        if self.type== "Wall":
            pygame.draw.rect(root,(0,255,255),(self.x+camX,self.y+camY,mapmultiplier,mapmultiplier),1)
        if self.type== "Blank":
            pygame.draw.rect(root,(32,32,32),(self.x+camX,self.y+camY,mapmultiplier,mapmultiplier))
```

then you can call the `draw` method:

```py
for walls in range(len(WallList)):
    WallList[walls].draw()
```

Comment: Thanks! new lesson learnt. You opened me a lot of doors. It works. Once I was going to do that, but I took Python too "logical" so I made a few errors.